# Validar si hay texto en una variable php

Tags: php

Cómo confirmo si hay texto en una variable, ya hice la prueba con este ejemplo pero no me sirve.

```
<?php
    $texto = "";
    
    if (count($texto) == 0)
    {
        echo "No hay";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Si hay";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Puedes usar `empty($variable)`

Comment: Debes acalarar que es lo que quieres ya que "validar si hay texto" es muy diferente a decir "validar si esta vacio". Ya que segun lo que dices te hago la pregunta: ¿Si hubiera numeros, no validaria? Y te doy la respuesta...puedes usar `!is_numeric($texto)` para validar que haya texto y no numeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Esta es una respuesta traducida de SO: [check if variable empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8777605/13758587) adaptada a la pregunta del OP

Si desea probar si una variable es *realmente* `NULL`, use el operador de identidad:

```
$texto === NULL  // FALSE == NULL is true, FALSE === NULL is false
is_null($texto )
```

Si desea verificar si una variable no está declarada:

```
!isset($texto )
```

O si la variable no está vacía, una cadena vacía, cero, ..:

```
empty($texto )
```

Si desea probar si una variable no es una cadena vacía, `!` también será suficiente:

```
!$texto
```

---

**Aclaraciones**

- Para tu caso es usar `empty` ya que para eso fue creado, como dice su documentacion:

> Determina si una variable está vacía

**Referencias**

- [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)
- [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función `strlen()` la cual obtiene la longitud del string dado, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$text ="";

$length = strlen($text);
if(!$length){
    echo "No hay texto";
} else {
    echo "El tamñao es: $length".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Puedes probarlo  [aquí](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/def6b11d1187cc625523016963500d7f7c1d7371)

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias opciones:

```
if (empty($variable)){ hacer algo }

if (is_null($variable)){ hacer algo }

if ($variable == false){ hacer algo }

if (!strlen($variable)){ hacer algo }

if (!$variable){ hacer algo }
```

Cualquiera de esas sirven, **personalmente uso la función empty**.